# Minimizar aplicación de java al SystemTray

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

Quisiera saber cómo puedo agregar mi ejecutable de una aplicación de `JAVA` a la barra de notificaciones junto donde esta el reloj.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas la clase [SystemTray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html)

Como pasos:

Ver si esta disponible con

```
SystemTray.isSupported()
```

Obtener el `SystemTray`

```
SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
```

Crear un `TrayIcon` que será el icono visible al usuario

```
TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(unaImagen, "tooltip");
```

Crear un `PopupMenu` y ponerlo en el `TrayIcon`

```
 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
  //Aqui se añaden todos los elementos
  .....
  trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);
```

Y agregar nuestro icono al `SystemTray`

```
 tray.add(trayIcon);
```